# Multi SELECT SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Writing my first nested `SELECT` statement and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I need to grab the `CompanyCode` and `AgentId` from the `UniqueAgentIdtoUniqueAgentId` table. However, I only need the ones that show up in a query from another table. The common link between the rows will the the `UniqueAgentId` column (basically I need to grab the `CompanyCode` and `AgentId` from the rows that contain the same `UniqueAgentId` as come up in the nested query).

When I write this query out, I get the extremely helpful message

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Query:

```
SELECT 
    CompanyCode, AgentId
FROM 
    UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId un
WHERE 
    un.UniqueAgentId = 
       (SELECT UniqueAgentId 
        FROM 
            (SELECT q.LastChangeDate, a.UniqueAgentId 
             FROM QueueUpdates q, AgentProductTraining a 
             WHERE a.LastChangeDate >= q.LastChangeDate)
       )
```

EDIT 
Thank you very much for the responses. Using every single query below, however I keep getting the same error message: Invalid object name 'UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId'. This is odd to me because this is an actual table on the database that SQL Management Studio can see.

SECOND EDIT
This turned out to simply be a spelling error. The new error is "The conversion of the varchar value '3030111101' overflowed an int column." Not quite sure what this means either...

FINAL EDIT
I was attempting to compare a char with an it, which caused this error. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Studio

Comment: *SQL Management Studio* is the GUI used to connect to the database - but it's still not the **database product** you're using. From your post and from that "Management Studio", I assume it's **SQL Server**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a subquery in many databases, you need to give it an alias:

```
SELECT CompanyCode, AgentId
FROM UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId un
WHERE un.UniqueAgentId = 
      (SELECT UniqueAgentId 
       FROM (SELECT q.LastChangeDate, a.UniqueAgentId 
             FROM QueueUpdates q, AgentProductTraining a 
             WHERE a.LastChangeDate >= q.LastChangeDate
            ) t
      )
```

However, your inner query might return multiple values, and you don't need two nested queries:

```
SELECT CompanyCode, AgentId
FROM UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId un
WHERE un.UniqueAgentId in
      (SELECT UniqueAgentId 
       FROM QueueUpdates q, AgentProductTraining a 
       WHERE a.LastChangeDate >= q.LastChangeDate
      )
```

And, it is more proper to use JOIN syntax in this case:

```
SELECT CompanyCode, AgentId
FROM UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId un
WHERE un.UniqueAgentId in
      (SELECT UniqueAgentId 
       FROM QueueUpdates q join
            AgentProductTraining a 
            on a.LastChangeDate >= q.LastChangeDate
      )
```

That should help.

Comment: I keep getting the error message "Invalid object name 'UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId'." I'm not sure what this means as this is actually a table in the database.

Comment: Well, it would mean that it is not a table in the database.  Perhaps you are in the wrong database, so the query processor doesn't find the object.  Perhaps the name is mispelled.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CompanyCode, AgentId
    FROM UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId un
    WHERE un.UniqueAgentId = 
    (
        SELECT UniqueAgentId 
         FROM AgentProductTraining  where UniqueAgentId IN
           (
            SELECT q.LastChangeDate, a.UniqueAgentId 
            FROM QueueUpdates q, AgentProductTraining a 
            WHERE a.LastChangeDate >= q.LastChangeDate
            )
    )
```

Comment: Both of these give the result "Invalid object name 'UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId'." This has me a bit confused since this is a table that the intellisense can actually see..

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an alias, which is your actual reported issue, and likely use the `IN` clause instead of the `=` operator for multiple returns:

```
SELECT CompanyCode
    ,AgentId
FROM UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId un
WHERE un.UniqueAgentId in (
        SELECT UniqueAgentId
        FROM (
            SELECT q.LastChangeDate
                ,a.UniqueAgentId
            FROM QueueUpdates q
                ,AgentProductTraining a
            WHERE a.LastChangeDate >= q.LastChangeDate
            ) a 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery may return more than 1 value. You must use IN.
You can also avoid the two subqueries and use only one.

```
SELECT CompanyCode, AgentId
FROM UniqueAgentIdToUniqueAgentId un
WHERE un.UniqueAgentId IN 
(
    SELECT a.UniqueAgentId 
    FROM QueueUpdates q, AgentProductTraining a 
    WHERE a.LastChangeDate >= q.LastChangeDate
)
```

**Note** that in this way you obtain a **cartesian product** of table aliases **q** and **a**.
I don't know if this is what you want; maybe a join should be better.